# Real Time Clock arduino

Tags: arduino

I would like to execute a program on arduino every hour. So I would like to have an led, (lets say the internal led 13) every hour for 10 seconds on, and then off, the next full hour the same (led-on for one min and led-off the rest of the time) and so on.
I have the DS3231 real time clock.

Thank you in advance
Markus

Comment: Have you read the tutorial on Adafruit? https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ds3231-precision-rtc-breakout/overview there is a link to a library.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Yes I did read it, but in that library there seems to be no comand to execute something every minute, our, secon (so there is no alarm setting).

Answer (score 1):

what you have to do is to use the RTClib library from Adafruit. With it you can control the clock and know what time it is.

Use for example the EEPROM to store where you have been in each moment and so if it is turned off, you can continue where you left off.

I also leave a link of a tutorial on this library with the DS3231 that, although it is in Spanish, you can translate it with Google Translate :) https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/reloj-con-arduino-rtc /

Comment: Thank you, the Spanish tutorial is really great. Your tipps, bring me a lot closer to the goal!